# AbsolutePath not found when executing the JAR file but it works from the IDE

Tags: java, absolute-path

I have few text files in /src/res/. I am referencing the the file path using AbsolutePath

```
static String file1Path = new File("src/res/file1.txt").getAbsolutePath();
    static String file2Path = new File("file2.txt").getAbsolutePath();
    static String file3Path = new File("src/res/file3.txt").getAbsolutePath();
```

Then I use  the File Path to read a the file's contents in the following way.

```
private String[] listFile1Lines() throws IOException {
        return new LineBuilder(file1Path).build();
    }

    private String[] listFile2Lines() throws IOException {
        return new LineBuilder(file2Path).build();
    }
```

This works just fine in the IDE, but when I execute the jar file, I get ..../dist/src/res/file1.txt not found

Comment: Try System.out.println(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()); and run from IDE and the jar file. You will get the idea.

Comment: "Src" does not exist when the code is compiled and packaged, your should NEVER reference any path which contains "src" for this very reason. In your case you should be using Class#getResource(...) and pass it "/res/file1.txt" as the path. This does mean that you will no longer be able to reference these resources as a File, because they're not, they are bytes stores in a zip file.  This is also a very common problem

Comment: is there a way that I can create a temporary file. or copy the files under src to dist/lib because right now, I have to copy the files manually every time I clean and build.